# Error converting datetime string to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I get an error when I try to convert a `datetime` string to a `datetime` object:

```
df['R_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['R_DATE'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

Error is:

```
...
File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 141, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
  ValueError: time data 'Mon Oct 18 00:00:00 EDT 2021' 
    does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y' (match)
```

From what I can tell format appears to match the `datetime` string value. I'm not sure if the timezone value (EDT) is causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm. found the answer I was looking for.

```
import dateutil

tzdict = {'EST': dateutil.tz.gettz('America/New_York'),
      'EDT': dateutil.tz.gettz('America/New_York')}

df['R_DATE'] = df['R_DATE'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, tzinfos=tzdict)
```